# trying to interrogate sub-dictionaries within ansible

Tags: ansible

I've read a few topics about this now, but I'm finding it difficult to understand how to access a sub dictionary as I would a dictionary within a playbook.  In this example, the dictionary is ansible_net_interfaces.

For example, I can use the following code to grab a list of all the interfaces and their specific information:

```
- name: test debug
  debug:
    msg:
      - "{{ item.key }}:"
      - "  description: {{ item.value.description | default('', true) }}"
      - "  ip_address: {{ item.value.ipv4.0.address | default('', true) }}"
      - "  subnet: {{ item.value.ipv4.0.subnet | default('', true) }}"
  when:
      - item.key != "Async0/0/0"
      - item.key != "Dialer1"
  with_dict: "{{ ansible_net_interfaces }}"
```

But what I can't figure out is how to access the sub-dictionary of each interface in the same way at the same time.  In this instance I've used a filter to assign a null value if none is present to prevent the play exiting, but what I'd like to know, is how to reference the key/value pairs in each sub dictionary in the same manner I'm referencing each interface with "item.key".  My reasoning is that I can then loop through and capture each value without ever needing to know beforehand what key value pairs are assigned.  It may not be practical in the end in this case, but it's something I'd like to know anyway.

Things I've tried so far:
with_nested (perhaps only works with lists and not dictionaries?)
with_items and a seperate custom list of interfaces
with_subelements
various combinations and syntax of all of the above.

example of what I'm trying to do:

```
- name: second loop
  debug:
    for interfaces in {{ ansible_net_interfaces }}:
      msg: "{{ ansible_net_interfaces[interfaces].item.key }}"
```

I'm trying to loop through every interface in ansible_net_facts, and within that loop, trying to list all the key/pairs in that interface.

Essentially, since a dictionary is an array, how do I target the index of a sub-dictionary - say the value of item 0 (Which I think is Interface description) in item 0 (an dictionary of interface attributes) in ansible_net_interfaces (a dictionary of interfaces)

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to do. Maybe show an example of what you would like the code to look like (even if it doesn't work)?

Comment: I've updated with an example, I hope that makes it a bit clearer!

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're after. When you say "list all the key/pairs in that interface", do you mean you want to list the values of `.description` and `.ipv4` without having to specify them? In any case, if you're just printing data, try just printing `item.value` - that should show you all of its information

Comment: that works, but that displays all information.  If I want to display the first key/pair in an interface, how would I do that?